# How do I configure Apexcharts on Rails 7.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apexcharts, stimulusjs, hotwire-rails, importmap-rails

I'm using Stimulus

It returns in the console:

Failed to register controller: indicators-chart (controllers/indicators_chart_controller) SyntaxError: The requested module 'apexcharts' does not provide an export named 'default'

I've already pinned importmap.rb:

pin 'apexcharts', to: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts'

I already added it to package.json:

"apexcharts": "^3.45.1",I called the stimulus controller: import ApexCharts from 'apexcharts'; (Tried with { Apexcharts } and ApexCharts)

I expected a graph to be rendered and not give this error!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

ApexCharts, when loaded from a CDN, may not use the standard default export that you would typically import with import ApexCharts from 'apexcharts'.

You can add ApexCharts to your app with Importmaps in two ways:

**1. without specifying a target:**

```
# config/importmap.rb
pin "apexcharts"
```

This approach allows Importmap to resolve and load ApexCharts automatically, offering simplicity but less control over the exact version and source of the library.

2. By specifying a CDN target:

```
# config/importmap.rb
pin "apexcharts", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:apexcharts@3.45.2/dist/apexcharts.common.js"
```

This method explicitly sets the version and source, ensuring compatibility with Importmaps and providing precise control over the library's version.

*This works because it specifically targets a module format compatible with Importmaps. The default CDN link from the ApexCharts documentation may not support Importmaps directly due to its export pattern.*

then import the module  at the top of your stimulus controller as you did.

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import ApexCharts from 'apexcharts'

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ['chart']

  connect() {
    this.chart = new ApexCharts(this.chartTarget, { chartOptions })
    this.chart.render()
  }
}
```

Note : Adding ApexCharts to your package.json file is redundant; Importmaps are designed for direct browser imports without a build step, whereas package.json is used for managing dependencies within a build process. Choose one method based on your application's architecture and deployment strategy.